# Show forward slash in haml?

Tags: haml

In haml, I want to display `5 / 174`. numerator, foward slash, denominator.

```
= @numerator
/
= denominator
```

My workaround:

```
= @numerator
- slash = "/"
= slash
= denominator
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would just use [interpolation with `#{}`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby_interpolation_) for something like this:

```
#{@numerator} / #{denominator}
```

(note you don’t need `=` at the start).

If you really want to start a line in Haml with the `/` character (or any other special character) you can [escape it with `\`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#escaping_) e.g.

```
= @numerator
\/
= denominator
```